# ¿Cómo crear un archivo JSON desde PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, json

Necesito construir un archivo **JSON** desde **PHP** con una secuencia específica, pero no sé como construirlo.

La secuencia es la siguiente:

```
[{"jornada":"A","colegios":["Salle","Belemitas"]},
{"jornada":"B","colegios":["Nazaret","Comfama","jega"]}]
```

La base de de datos es la siguiente:

```
id  |  colegio  |  jornada  |
-----------------------------
1   | Salle     | A         |
-----------------------------
2   | Nazaret   | B         |
-----------------------------
3   | Comfama   | B         |
-----------------------------
4   | Belemitas | A         |
-----------------------------
5   | Jega      | B         |
-----------------------------
6   | Rosario   | Unica     |
-----------------------------
```

Mi intento en PHP:

```
    $con = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $password, $database);
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "APP: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM ge_colegios ORDER BY jornada DESC;  ");


    $json = '[';


    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
        $char ='"';
        $json .= 
        '{

            ¿CÓMO CONSTRUYO LE SECUENCIA AQUÍ?

        },';
    }


    // buat menghilangkan koma diakhir array
    $json = substr($json,0,strlen($json)-1);

    $json .= ']';

    echo $json; 
    mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Gracias.

Comment: Crea tu arreglo normal, despues usa la función json_encode algo así:

$array = json_encode($array);

Answer (score 1):

Yo lo que hago es crearme un array y luego ir recorriendo los datos. Por último los codifico con el json_encode. Sería así:

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM ge_colegios ORDER BY jornada DESC;  ");

$datos = array();

foreach ($query as $row) {

    $datos[] = $row;

}

echo json_encode($datos);
```

Espero te ayude.
Suerte!

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM ge_colegios ORDER BY jornada DESC;");

$i = 0;
while ($array[$i] = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    $i++;
}

$json = json_encode($array);
echo $json;

mysqli_close($con);
```

La funcion mysqli_fetch_array() guarda los datos uno por uno cada vez que es ejecutada. Por lo que para tu caso, en lugar de hacer el formato JSON paso por paso en codigo puro, se lo dejamos en un arreglo listo para usarse en la funcion json_encode(). Esto logrado mediante un while() y un mysqli_fetch_array() que van guardando las columnas obtenidas en el arreglo.

Answer (score 0):

Para generar un json yo lo que utilizo este codigo:

`while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))`
    `{`
       `$json[]=array('valor1'=> $row['valor1'], 'valor2'=> $row['valor2']);`
`}`

`$json_string = json_encode($json);`
`echo $json_string;`

p/d: la variable json la creo dentro del while